# How are the properties of $GF(p)$ different from $GF(p^{n})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

I am trying to understand the concept of Galois fields from a beginner level, I read that Galois fields are of the form $GF(p^{n})$.

- What difference does it make conceptually to the properties of a field?
- Also why Galois extension field  elements considered as polynomials?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$GF(p^n)$ is the set of polynomials of degree less than $n$, whose $n$ coefficients are all in $GF(p)$.  Multiplication of polynomials is taken modulo $f(x)$, where $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ without any factors.
Note $p=0$ in both $GF(p)$ and $GF(p^n)$.

Comment: Why is it that $p = 0$ ?

Comment: When you multiply a polynomial by $p$, all its coefficients become multiples of $p$.  The remainder on dividing by $p$ is zero.  So all the coefficients are $\equiv 0\pmod p$, and the result is the zero polynomial in $GF(p^n)$.

Comment: Okay now I got it ! :) I also understood that $GF(p)$ can also be considered as an extension field where the highest degree $0$ !!!